# Delete item from array of object which has bot index or length with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
var menu =[
    co-cacola: {nom: "co-cacola", type: "boisson", prix: 1.3, image: "image-coca.png", quantity: 2}
    double cheese: {nom: "double cheese", type: "burger", prix: 4.5, image: "image-dboulec.jpg", quantity: 1}
    frites: {nom: "frites", type: "accompagnement", prix: 2, image: "image-frite.jpg", quantity: 1}
    poulet: {nom: "poulet", type: "viande", prix: 3, image: "image-poulet.png", quantity: 3}
]
```

Sorry for my poor English, I am beginner in JavaScript development !

My problem is that I would like to remove element or item (whatever) from my array, but something strange this array has not index

how can I do that ?

I've used for loop, but nothing seems to work as the menu has not length! console (has returned).

Moreover when I use `for` in loop, I can retrieve item but I can delete item as I do not have its index!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not an array, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, don't worry about your English skills, here are many helpers they will help and edit your question, provide snipped code you have tried to remove?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are lists of elements separated by comma. In your case the array is declared incorrectly. The `:` is wrongly placed. Your array should be something like this:

```
var array = [
    { "Coca-cola": { key: "some value" } }, /* other array elements */
]
```

This way you can use [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function to remove array elements

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, I have read some more informations about array since my question so I'm going to correct my mistake ! Anyway thank you for all ! Merci

Comment: Glad to help you